# Unclear - redundant constructors in additive generic programming

Tags: generics, functional-programming, scheme, sicp

Section 2.4.3 gives a detailed example of how tag dispatching can be used to write generic code which is also easily extensible:

Assuming the existence of `put op type item` and `put op type` for registering and retrieving type-specific operations from a table, two clients, one working or complex numbers via rectangular coordinates, the other one via polar coordinates, define their own versions of selectors (`real-part`, `imag-part`, `magnitude`, and `angle`) and constructors (`make-from-real-imag` and `make-from-mag-ang`), and register all of those into the table. The generic counterparts of those selectors then pick the right implementation from the table, based on a tag that constructors systematically attach to complex numbers at construction time.

As regards the constructors, these 4 are registered

```lisp
(define (install-rectangular-package)
  …
  (put 'make-from-real-imag '(rectangular)
       (lambda (x y) (tag (make-from-real-imag x y))))
  (put 'make-from-mag-ang '(rectangular)
       (lambda (r a) (tag (make-from-mag-ang r a))))
  …
  'done)
(define (install-polar-package)
  …
  (put 'make-from-real-imag '(polar)
       (lambda (x y) (tag (make-from-real-imag x y))))
  (put 'make-from-mag-ang '(polar)
       (lambda (r a) (tag (make-from-mag-ang r a))))
  …
  'done)
```

but only 2 are exported

```lisp
(define (make-from-real-imag x y)
    ((get 'make-from-real-imag 'rectangular) x y))
(define (make-from-mag-ang r a)
    ((get 'make-from-mag-ang 'polar) r a))
```

I do see that it is not necessary to export the other two, because for instance using `make-from-real-imag` from one or the other module affects an implementation detail (how the complex number is stored), and nothing more.

But my point is, why defining those constructors in the first place, if they are fundamentally redundant?

Answer (score 0):

`make-from-real-imag` and `make-from-mag-ang` are the global scope functions that you are going to call in programs to read from the bidimensional table of types.

The `put` calls fill the bidimensional table and the `get` calls reads the operators from the given types for the given operator.

The global operators are defined beyond the abstraction barrier of the user API, while the other operators that fill the table (encoded as properties of symbols) are defined below the abstraction barrier of the user level.

PS:

This is not how in real languages the generics is implemented.  In real languages the generics are implemented using a trie-search or a BDD-search, where at ith node level it's made a dispatch depending on the type of the ith argument.